# Why doesn't this work? =Sept!A2;{INT(A2)}

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to import data from one spreadsheet to another and I want to convert a date with time into a date without time.  Within a spreadsheet =INT(A2) works great but something like doesn't work =Sept!A2;{INT(A2)}

doesn't work =Sept!A2;{INT(A2)}

It gives a parse error.

I was hoping for a date without a time

Comment: Did you try =INT(Sept!A2) ?

Answer (score 0):

The formula quoted in the question errors out because it is using an incorrect syntax. To convert a datetime value to a date serial without the fractional day, i.e., time part, use `datevalue()` or `int()`, like this:

```
=dateserial(Sept!A2)
```

Format the result cell as **Format > Number > Date**.

In the event you want to convert the datetime to a date for viewing only, use `to_date()`, like this:

```
=to_date(Sept!A2)
```

The latter formula will retain the underlying value but change the presentation so that only the date is visible.

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219), [datevalue()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) and [to_date()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239).

Comment: Ok I am trying to use the format as listed before because it is part of large equation =INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(x="", "absent", IF((x>0)*(x<40000), "present", TEXT(x, "d/m/yy")))) (QUERY({Sept!A1:B20; {(INT(A:A)), B:B}}, "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1", 1)))

Comment: In a `query()`, you can convert the value to a date by using `toDate(Col1)` in the query statement. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).